# $\mathbb{Q}\times(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\cup(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\times\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: analysis

For $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2,$ say $(a, b) \in A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ if $a$ and $b$ are both rational numbers, or $a$ and $b$ are both irrational numbers; and $(a, b) \in B=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ otherwise.

Given any two distinct $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2,$ can we draw a continuous curve from $x$ to $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that it does not pass any element in $B?$

Context of this question: I am trying to prove that $B$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The answer is "it depends".  $$$$
Example 1: Take $x = (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ and $y = (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})$. Then the line passed by $x$ and $y$ contains the point $z =  (\sqrt{2},2)  \in B$ $$$$
Example 2: Take $x = (1, 2)$ and $y =(1,3)$. Then the line passed by $x$ and $y$ contains only the points in $A$

Comment: I know this is impossible, but I don't know how to give out a rigorous proof. Could anyone give some hints?

Comment: @NN2 Thank you! But I think your example is only for straight lines. If we are allowed to use any continuous line to connect the two points, how can we show that this is impossible?

Comment: @2512490741 I modified my previous comment by adding another example. The statement depends on the 2 points $x,y$

Comment: Please * make the title and the post match each other, and * describe the efforts you've made to answer the question and the context of the question.

Comment: @NN2 The fact that the line segment from $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ to $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})$ does not avoid $B$ is not sufficient to show that no path from $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ to $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})$ avoids $B$.

Comment: @L.F. Ok, I see. I thought the topic owner said a straight line passed the two points $x,y$

Comment: @2512490741 Do you mean a continuous line or a continuous curve?

Comment: @kc9jud I think both would apply. Are there any difference between them? lol

Comment: A continuous line is straight, i.e., does not have any curvature. That means that, once you set the end points, there is only one straight line (segment) connecting the two points. I think that's what @NN2 was getting at with "it depends".

Comment: @kc9jud I change "line" to "curve", thanks for your help!

Comment: About the motivation, do you mean that you want to prove $A$ is connected? $B$ is not connected: $\{x > y\}$ and $\{x < y\}$ is a disconnection.

Comment: @ronno Oh I see... But I was trying to prove that B is connected :( Thank you for your counterexample!

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting question in general whether $A$ being dense in $X$ implies that $A\times A$ is dense in $X\times X$ for a general topological space $X$. Maybe someone can answer this general question.

However, in the case that $A=\Bbb Q$ and $X=\Bbb R$, it is easy to show directly. The pair $(\mathbb R,d)$ is a metric space, where $d(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-y)^2}$. Since we [already know](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m127a_19/rat_dense.pdf) that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, we know that for all $\epsilon>0$, that
$$\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q}\mathbb B^1(q,\epsilon)=\mathbb R$$
Where $\mathbb B^1(x,r)$ is the one dimensional ball $\mathbb B^1(x,r)=\{s\in\mathbb R:d(x,s)<r\}$. This automatically means that
$$\bigcup_{\boldsymbol q\in\mathbb Q^2}\mathbb B^2(\boldsymbol q,\epsilon)=\mathbb R^2$$
For all $\epsilon>0$. Because $\mathbb R^2$ is trivially dense in $\mathbb R^2$, we know that all of the sets
$$S_n=\bigcup_{\boldsymbol q\in\mathbb Q^2}\mathbb B^2(\boldsymbol q,1/n)$$
are dense in $\mathbb R^2$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. [THEREFORE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set#Density_in_metric_spaces),
$$\bigcap _{n\in\mathbb N}S_n = \mathbb Q^2$$
Is also dense in $\mathbb R^2$. QED.

Comment: $A \times A$ is dense in $X \times X$ if $A$ is dense in $X$: any non-empty open set in $X \times X$ contains some basic open set, ie $U \times V$ for some $U, V$ non-empty open in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $A$ is arc-connected. This follows from the fact that a line segment which is a part of the graph of $ax + b$ where both $a,b$ are rational and $a$ is not $0$ contains only points from $A$. With this in mind, given two points, say $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in A$ one can constructs an arc connecting them and contained in $A$. The process is as follows. If both points are rational this is easy ( just take line segment connecting them). If one of them, say $(x_2,y_2)$ has both coordinates irrational then take a point with distance, say $< 1/2$ from it which has both coordinates rational and connect it to $(x_1,y_1)$ by an arc contained in $A$. Then, in the next step one finds a point, say with distance $<1/4$ from $(x_2,y_2)$ and extend the first arc by a line segment to its end to the new point. Then you continue by induction. You have a family of arcs which converges (uniformly) to and an arc joining $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. Similar construction works if both $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ are irrational.
So, what matters here is not so much that $A$ is arc connected but the construction itself. That is, that we can build "circle like" (that closed) curves which are contained in $A$. Then to show that $B$ is not connected you take interior points and exterior points of such curve. Both sets are non-empty and open and their sum is $B$. So, $B$ is not connected hence it can not be arc-connected.

Comment: Could you give an explanation why "converging to" a point means "connected with" the point? (Because for $(x_1, y_1)$ irrational, it seems that the process cannot terminate.) This is the only part I get confused about your answer.

Comment: We just extend those pieace wise linear curves. The process converges to curve with end point which could be irrational. This is all good but much simpler solution is just to take 4 sided polygon with sides not parallel to axis,  that is defined by lines ax + b with a,b rational, and a - not zero. Then you proceed by the same argument as above.